# Can FlyCheck be used with Komodo(for Django) for checking syntax on the fly?

Tags: django-templates, komodo, komodoedit, syntax-checking, flycheck

I want to use Komodo IDE for building one Django project.I want to use flycheck syntax checker so that it indicates the syntax errors on the fly.If fly-check cannot be integrated with Komodo,is there any other possibility to syntax checking on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Goto Toolbox=>Add=>New Command
- Enter the emacs command line arguments in the Run field:

  ```
  emacs eval('(progn
   (flycheck-declare-checker go-gofmt
     "A Go syntax and style checker using the gofmt utility."
     :command '("gofmt" source-inplace)
     :error-patterns '(("^\\(?1:.*\\):\\(?2:[0-9]+\\):\\(?3:[0-9]+\\): \\(?4:.*\\)$" error))
     :modes 'go-mode)
   (add-to-list 'flycheck-checkers 'go-gofmt)))
  ```
- Check all the boxes
- Enter the path to emacs in the `Start In` field
- Click the `Key Binding` tab
- Use <kbd>Ctrl+0</kbd> as the `New Key Sequence`
- Press <kbd>Ctrl+A,Ctrl+0</kbd>

**References**

- [Komodo Documentation: Run Commands](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/8.0/run.html)
- [Emacs Wiki: Flycheck](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Flycheck)